# Better way to have script send email to every row, for once?

Tags: php, arrays, email, foreach

I currently writing on a script that sends out email to admin when assignee's pass is expiring in 3 months time. However, I'm on a  bottleneck right now, as the email sends out only one email and not the intended multiple single email on each assignee. It should also send those that is today + 3 months (i.e. expiry on 2013-06-02 will be send out today, and only once). value is store as DATE (yyyy-mm-dd) in db.

I suppose for it to run once I should have a checker with my sql where sendemail(a field in db table for assignee) = 0?

Is my current data store in an array? and if so, I need to foreach() to have the email send to each entry that meets the condition?

I have close to 1000 entries in my db and hopefully the above code or the amended one won't choke up the server, which runs the script after office hours.

Any expert can assist in perfecting the script or point me the correct direction? Any help is great help!!!

Thanks

(PS.-Credit to peterm in pointing me the correct direction for the email to work in the first place & Pardon me if mysql_* is deprecated. I have no idea how to use pdo at this point of time. Once everything is working I might edit them again to adopt pdo for future proofing)

This is what I have right now:

```
/execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_lead WHERE pass_expiry = DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL      
3 MONTH)");

if (!$result) {
//handle your error
die('The query failed.');
}


//fetch tha data from the database 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$subject = $row['company_name']."'s"." work pass is expiry soon";
$emailBody = "Company: ".$row['company_name']." \n"."Comment: ".$row['comment']."   
\n"."Contact: ".$row['contact']." \n";
}


if(mail($to, $subject, $emailBody, $headers)) {
echo $emailBody;
echo 'Email sent successfully!';
} else {
echo $emailBody;
die('Failure: Email was not sent!');

}   
//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off... you shouldn't use select *, rather select only the columns you need, in addition to your primary key, to take advantage of indices:

```
//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT comment,company_name,contact FROM tbl_lead WHERE pass_expiry = DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 3 MONTH)");
```

You are also not setting `$to` in your while loop, which may go to explain why you're sending only one email.

Comment: Hi hd1, currently my $to is set to one fix email address which is the overall administrator. There are 5 administrators altogether and each is in charge of their own entries. Their email can be stored in each entry.

Comment: So you need to send the admins separate emails for each row?

Comment: Yes, say theres 10 entries each for admin A and admin B, of which 5 are expiring. Than 5 seperate email to the respective admin.